# Javascript Tabs Accordion Issue

Tags: javascript, tabs

I have created a tabs accordion which is working properly. However their behaviour is not as i want it to be. At the current tabs accordion when i press one of the tabs it will show the content inside it, and when i press another tab it will open also. What i would like to have happen is when i click one of the tabs to be the only one that is showing and the rest of the tabs to be closed. Hope someone can help me to add that extra code that i need to make it work.

```js
var tabsContainer = document.getElementById("tabsContainer");

var tabUl = document.getElementById("tabs-ul");

var tabOne = document.getElementById("tab-one");
var tabTwo = document.getElementById("tab-two");
var tabThree = document.getElementById("tab-three");

var tabOneContent = document.getElementById("tab-one-content");
var tabTwoContent = document.getElementById("tab-two-content");
var tabThreeContent = document.getElementById("tab-three-content");

function openTabOne() {
  if (tabOneContent.className == "toggleTab") {
    tabOneContent.className = "";
  } else {
    tabOneContent.className = "toggleTab";
  }
}

function openTabTwo() {
  if (tabTwoContent.className == "toggleTab") {
    tabTwoContent.className = "";
  } else {
    tabTwoContent.className = "toggleTab";
  }
}

function openTabThree() {
  if (tabThreeContent.className == "toggleTab") {
    tabThreeContent.className = "";
  } else {
    tabThreeContent.className = "toggleTab";
  }
}

tabOne.addEventListener("click", openTabOne);
tabTwo.addEventListener("click", openTabTwo);
tabThree.addEventListener("click", openTabThree);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 14px;
  background: silver;
}
#tabsContainer {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px solid #a70d89;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.77);
  ;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background: #4c99ac;
  color: #7910c6;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#tabsContainer > div {
  margin: 20px 0px;
  display: none;
}
#tab-one-content.toggleTab,
#tab-two-content.toggleTab,
#tab-three-content.toggleTab {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabsContainer">
  <ul id="tabs-ul">
    <li id="tab-one">Tab One</li>
    <li id="tab-two">Tab Two</li>
    <li id="tab-three">Tab Three</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab-one-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat quam nesciunt, architecto earum! Beatae explicabo voluptatum rem odit sint dolorem, voluptatem, est iure quia ab voluptates excepturi ratione debitis praesentium.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-two-content">
    Placeat quam nesciunt, architecto earum! Beatae explicabo voluptatum rem odit sint dolorem, voluptatem, est iure quia ab voluptates excepturi ratione debitis praesentium.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-three-content">
    Beatae explicabo voluptatum rem odit sint dolorem, voluptatem, est iure quia ab voluptates excepturi ratione debitis praesentium.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to deselect a tab and show no tabs? It looks like that is how your code currently works but you don't mention it in the problem.

Comment: I would like to toggle between tabs. I don't want the tab content to stack on each other when the tabs are clicked. I would like to show the content only for the tab that i clicked on.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, currently if you click a tab that is already open it will be closed. Do you want it to work so that you can close all the tabs (so no content is visible, only the tabs across the top) or should one always stay open?

Comment: I would like to have one open always.

Comment: Ok, my original answer made it so they could be closed. I updated it so one would always be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the class from the tabs that you don't want open anymore, here is a possible way to do it.

```js
var tabsContainer = document.getElementById("tabsContainer");

var tabUl = document.getElementById("tabs-ul");

var tabOne = document.getElementById("tab-one");
var tabTwo = document.getElementById("tab-two");
var tabThree = document.getElementById("tab-three");
var tabPanels = [
  document.getElementById("tab-one-content"),
  document.getElementById("tab-two-content"),
  document.getElementById("tab-three-content")
];

function showTab(tabIndex) {
  for(var i = 0; i < tabPanels.length; i++) {
    tabPanels[i].className = i == tabIndex ? 'toggleTab' : '';
  }
}

function openTabOne() {
    showTab(0);
}

function openTabTwo() {
    showTab(1);
}

function openTabThree() {
    showTab(2);
}

openTabOne();

tabOne.addEventListener("click", openTabOne);
tabTwo.addEventListener("click", openTabTwo);
tabThree.addEventListener("click", openTabThree);
```

```css
* {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 14px;
    background:silver;
}

#tabsContainer {
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:3px solid #a70d89;
    padding:20px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.77);;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:5px 20px;
    background:#4c99ac;
    color:#7910c6;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#tabsContainer > div {
    margin: 20px 0px;
    display: none;
}

#tab-one-content.toggleTab, #tab-two-content.toggleTab, #tab-three-content.toggleTab {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabsContainer">
   <ul id="tabs-ul">
       <li id="tab-one">Tab One</li>
       <li id="tab-two">Tab Two</li>
       <li id="tab-three">Tab Three</li>
   </ul>
   <div id="tab-one-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat quam nesciunt, architecto earum! Beatae explicabo voluptatum rem odit sint dolorem, voluptatem, est iure quia ab voluptates excepturi ratione debitis praesentium.
   </div>
   <div id="tab-two-content">
             Placeat quam nesciunt, architecto earum! Beatae explicabo voluptatum rem odit sint dolorem, voluptatem, est iure quia ab voluptates excepturi ratione debitis praesentium.
   </div>
   <div id="tab-three-content">
            Beatae explicabo voluptatum rem odit sint dolorem, voluptatem, est iure quia ab voluptates excepturi ratione debitis praesentium.
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @NoName84 Great! Can you mark it as the accepted answer if it helped you out so the question is marked as answered?

Comment: Your answer is working properly and i have marked it. However if its ok, can you please create the same code using a for loop?

Comment: @NoName84 Where do you want a for loop? To replace the `forEach` call?

Comment: Yes. I would like to replace the forEach loop with a for loop